# How to get a custom return value from an SSH command?

Tags: bash, ssh, return, sudo

I'm trying to get feedback from SSH but I'm unsure how to go about it. My SSH command is structured as follows:

```
ssh exampleuser@exampledomain.com 'sudo bash -s' < examplebashscript.sh
```

I have rsa keys set up and the script runs exactly as expected on the remove server. The end of my bash script is  as follows

```
if [ $ERROR_COUNT -ne 0 ]; then
    ...
    exit 10
else
    ...
    exit 20
fi
```

However, if I `echo $?` I get `0` as my response. I presume this 0 is being returned because the SSH command ran successfully? How do I return a a value from the SSH command? I want to return a 10 if there were errors when the script ran and 20 if there were no errrors

Comment: I believe this should be working. Does this work without `sudo`? Does it work if you put the script on the remote host and run it from there (instead of through `bash -s`)?

Comment: The script will run without sudo but it will create errors as some of the commands in the script require sudo to run successfully. The script does work when I upload it to the remote host and run it directly there. However `echo $?` still returns `0`

Comment: If you run the script on the host manually do you get your exit codes? I meant does a simpler script (that doesn't need sudo) return correct exit status from this workflow?

Comment: a simple non sudo script still returns 0

Comment: When run through ssh like that? What about when run manually via an interactive ssh session? If you can't get the exit code you want from the script in the first place you are going to have a hard time getting this to work in the non-interactive case.

Comment: I get custom return from ssh just fine, the problem must be sudo

Comment: This should work, and it does work for me. Can you post a complete test case and session output?